# How to use getItem(x, ...) in sparkR and how to subset a particular value in column?

Tags: r, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, sparkr

I have a sparkR data frame, `cust_sales`, i need to extract only the value `CQ98901282` from the column `cust_id`, in R we use `cust_sales$cust_id[3]`.

My sugession is can we use `getItem(x, ...)` to extract, if so
argument "x" will be column `cust_sales$cust_id`

1. what will come in argument "..."
2. If my sugession is wrong what is the usage of `getItem(x, ...)` and how it can be used in my example.

   ```
   +----------+----------+-----------+
   |   cust_id|      date|Total_trans|
   +----------+----------+-----------+
   |CQ98901280|2015-06-06|          1|
   |CQ98901281|2015-05-01|          1|
   |CQ98901282|2015-05-02|          1|
   |CQ98901283|2015-05-03|          1|
   |CQ98901284|2015-04-01|          6|
   |CQ98901285|2015-04-02|          8|
   |CQ98901286|2015-04-03|         13|
   |CQ98901287|2015-04-04|          3|
   |CQ98901288|2015-04-05|          3|
   |CQ98901289|2015-04-08|         16|
   ```

TIA,
Arun

Answer (score 1):

Spark data frames don't support random row access and you have a wrong idea how `getItem` function works. It is  intended for data extraction from non-atomic fields like maps or arrays:

```r
> writeLines('{"foo": [0, 1], "bar": {"x": 3, "y": 4}}', "example.json")
> df <- SparkR::jsonFile(sqlContext, "example.json")
> printSchema(df)
root
 |-- bar: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- x: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- y: long (nullable = true)
 |-- foo: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)
> select(df, getItem(df$bar, "x"), getItem(df$bar, "y")) %>% head()
  bar[x] bar[y]
1      3      4
```

For some reason I couldn't make it work with arrays but using PySpark

```py
>>> df = sqlContext.read.json("example.json")
>>> df.select(df.foo.getItem(0)).show()
>>> df.select(df.foo.getItem(0), df.foo.getItem(1), df.bar.getItem("x")).show()
+------+------+------+
|foo[0]|foo[1]|bar[x]|
+------+------+------+
|     0|     1|     3|
+------+------+------+
```